# Use a vararg function in a vararg function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to call a variadic function in a variadic function. The code does not give an error, but the resulting values are incorrect. What is the correct way to do this?

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void SecondFunction (int count, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    AddValues(count, args);
    va_end(args);
};

void AddValues(int count, ...) {
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, count);

   for(int i=count; i--; )
      processItem(va_arg(args, void*));

   va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the way you're implementing this, I have a gut feeling that you are trying to use the feature for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work, but you can create a similar function that uses a `va_list` argument. That is exactly why functions such as `vsyslog` and `vprintf` exists. In its simplest form:

```
void vAddValues(int count, va_list args) {
    int i;
    for (i = count; i--; )
        processItem(va_arg(args, void *));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read more carefully [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) or the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and documentation on [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) in C.

You need to use `va_list` and probably `va_copy`

Read also about the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of your particular C implementation. There is a detailed wikipedia page about [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) which is motivating the wording of the standard.

For inspiration, look at functions such as [vprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vprintf.3.html). In *practice* their implementation in [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) [C standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) such as   [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/) should be interesting to you.

In theory (and in real life, in *some* cases on Linux with recent [GCC](https://gcc.gn%20u.org/), as a builtin) `vprintf` can be implemented in the compiler. But since you can take its address and pass it to some of your function, it also has to be a function in the C standard library.